# Unmark question as dupe

Tags: support, specific-question, moderation

I marked this question:
[How can I select an element with multiple classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/jquery-multiple-class-selector)

As a dupe of this question:
[jQuery - Selecting Multiple Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488305/jquery-selecting-multiple-classes)

In fact, it is not a dupe. I clicked the `Flag` button but there was no option to unmark as dupe. So I'm posting here so that the question does not get marked as per my recommendation, and also to ask how to unmark a question as a dupe.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions will not be marked as duplicates until there are a total of 5 close votes and the majority chose that the question was a duplicate (unless of course a mod marks it as duplicate which only takes 1 vote).

Currently, you cannot undo your close vote as duplicate; however, if a question is closed as a duplicate, you can vote to reopen it afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, Josh. Good to know.

Comment: You can also leave a comment explaining why it isn't a dup. Others will see this and hopefully be able to make a fair decision.